# Navigation with balanced CSS flex-wrap containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I really love the new CSS flexbox design possibilities. Especially `flex-wrap: wrap` can be a powerful tool to save some space (e.g. simple mobile navigation design pattern).

**My Situation**: I have this navigation, on desktops all items are lined in one line. With `flex:auto` the items fill up all the space. Now, when i resize the browser, at a certain point, when there is no more space left, flex-wrap automagically creates this second line for me.

See my small [DEMO](http://codepen.io/esher/pen/JiLms) or have a look at this picture:

[image]

**This is what tickles me**: Only the first item is in the second row (when the first wrap happened). That's not really balanced and gives a lot of attention on this item. What i want is to distribute them equally. Is there a **CSS-only** no-hacks-included way that i am missing here?

EDIT: I do this layout for a dynamic web app. This navigation should fit different views and situations. So i don't want to care how many items there are going to be. The markup should ideally be a simple `ul li` list (no extra rows, no extra classes). So i am really looking for some kind of CSS parameter magic.

EDIT2: For better understanding: `text-wrap: balance` is a proposal to do basically the same only with chunks of pure text for typography.

EDIT3: See Bootstrap CSS framework grid model for example. Here you various columns-widths. You need to define how much space a column takes (third, quarter), for each device-width, for example: This colums takes a quarter of the width on a desktop, but only half of the width on a phone. wouldn't it be much cooler when browser could justify that?

EDIT4: Think of CSS-columns, here the content spans across the columns, but the content direction is only possible in N-form (column by column), imagine the same in Z-form (line by line).

Comment: I did some more research. Seems to me that there is no elegant solution.

Comment: I've lost the sense of your question after edit. If you want plain markup - enjoy default multi-line algorithm. If you want custom behaviour - adjust markup accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that what you want can be achieved, but I would like very much to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to isolate the viewport width when this unwanted layout occurs. Apply the `flex-grow` property to the items you want to be larger than the others. For instance, you could set the first and last items to `flex-grow: 2;` and they would be twice as wide as the second and third items.

Comment: Thx. Also a neat idea. As i edited above: I don't know so much about the items in the list. Also my goal is to come by with as less as possible media queries.